Book about a small ship that rises out of the water when a flute or musical instrument is played
About 45 years ago, I read a book in the elementary library about a small ship that would rise from the water when a musical instrument/flute was played.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome Tippy. When you say a "small ship" do you mean something with a crew of only 45 on board, a sailing-ship, a miniature aircraft carrier - or do you mean a model ship?

It's a long shot, but a specific sound would call a boat in the L. Frank Baum book Glinda of Oz.

The under-water boat was not operated by machinery, but by certain mystic words uttered by Coo-ee-oh. They didn't know how to submerge it, or how to make the water-tight shield cover them again, or how to make the boat go back to the castle, or make it enter the little basement room where it was usually kept.

....

... how the boat had shot out from the basement of the sunken isle, obeying a magic word, and risen to the surface, where it opened and floated upon the water.

....

"Yes, I always carry one in my bag," replied the Wizard. He opened his black bag of magic tools and took out a brightly polished skeropythrope, which he handed to the Sorceress. Glinda had also brought a small wicker bag, containing various requirements of sorcery, and from this she took a parcel of powder and a vial of liquid. She poured the liquid into the skeropythrope and added the powder. At once the skeropythrope began to sputter and emit sparks of a violet color, which spread in all directions. The Sorceress instantly stepped into the middle of the boat and held the instrument so that the sparks fell all around her and covered every bit of the blackened steel boat. At the same time Glinda crooned a weird incantation in the language of sorcery, her voice sounding low and musical.

